# How to monitor MySQL socket using icinga2

Tags: mysql, monitoring, icinga2

I would like to monitor my MySQL server using icinga2 as the title shows above. My MySQL server uses a unix socket. I tried the following:

```
object Service "MYSQL" {
    import "generic-service"
    check_command = "mysql"
    vars.mysql_query_hostname = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
    vars.mysql_ignore_auth = true
    vars.mysql_port = 6800
    host_name = "mysql.server"
    }
```

and I restart the icinga2 service. When I check from icinga2 web, I have the following error for the MySQL service:
**Plugin Output
Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.2.4' (111)**

It seems that icinga2 can't check the MySQL service using the unix socket. Is there something wrong with the config I'm using?

**EDIT 1:**
So, I've installed icinga2 on the client and configured it as a satellite. I've been reading that icinga2 agent is the elegant way to monitor services on a remote service. Since this setup will stay, I'm willing to spend time and efforts to configure everything properly.

On the server, /etc/icinga2/conf.d/services.conf

```
apply Service "MySQL" {
import "generic-service"
check_command = "mysql"
command_endpoint = host.vars.client_endpoint
assign where host.vars.client_endpoint == "client1.example.com"
}
```

/etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts.conf

```
object Host "client1.example.com" {
import "generic-host"
address = "192.168.2.4"
vars.client_endpoint = "client1.example.com"
vars.mysql_hostname = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"
}
```

On the client, I've installed the required plugin "check_mysql" and icinga2 is running. When I check through the icinga2 web interface, I still get the following plugin output:
Plugin Output Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.2.4' (111)
It seems that it is still checking through TCP. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is Icinga2 runs on the same server of your MySQL service ? In this case you would have a problem in your command. Can you paste the detail of your command in your question.

In other case, to test a Unix socket for mysql which not listen on a TCP port, you must use NRPE or SSH to connect to your mysql server and check the service. The result will be send to your icinga2 server.

**EDIT 1 :**

If you want to test a service which has not a listener on the network on a remote server, you can use several things :

1. [check_by_ssh](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_by_ssh.html)

With that, you will be able to execute remote commands on your remote server and the answer of this command will be send to your icinga2 server. This solution impose a ssh configuration between yous servers.

2. [NRPE](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Monitoring-Agents/NRPE--2D-Nagios-Remote-Plugin-Executor/details)

Otherwise, you can install NRPE on the remote server and execute commands with their results will be send to your icinga2 server.

NRPE can be run on windows or linux.

I think these two solutions are more simple than install icinga2 as a satellite on all your servers to be supervised.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'm totally new to monitoring systems and icinga2 is my first. OK, sounds logical. Can it be done if I install icinga2 on the client that I want to monitor and configure it as a satellite?

Comment: I edited my answer, I think install satellite is complicated for just test a service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer and for your help! Actually, It's not a test setup. It's rather an actually setup with many clients but since I'm new to all this, I'm trying to add on client at a time and then configure all the services I need. I'll edit my answer to have a better understanding on how I configured MySQL check.